# ECS service did not stabilize

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49175840/3317808) did not have pointers for this problem, because rollback deletes the stack.

---

Below is the CloudFormation template, written to launch Jenkins docker container in ECS container instance(DesiredCount: 1), in default public subnet.

Jenkins docker image is publicly available in dockerhub, which is launched in ECS container instance.

We used ECS optimised AMI image(`ami-05958d7635caa4d04`) `ca-central-1` region, that run docker version `18.06.1`.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Jenkins Stack",
    "Parameters":{
        "VpcId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "The target VPC Id"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
            "Description": "The target subnet Id"
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The key pair that is allowed SSH access"
        }
    },
    "Resources":{
        "EC2Instance":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties":{
                "ImageId": "ami-05958d7635caa4d04",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId"},
                "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName"},
                "SecurityGroupIds": [ { "Ref": "EC2InstanceSecurityGroup"} ],
                "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref" : "EC2InstanceProfile"},
                "UserData":{
                    "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["", [
                        "#!/bin/bash\n",
                        "echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref": "EcsCluster" }, " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
                        "groupadd -g 1000 jenkins\n",
                        "useradd -u 1000 -g jenkins jenkins\n",
                        "mkdir -p /ecs/jenkins_home\n",
                        "chown -R jenkins:jenkins /ecs/jenkins_home\n"
                    ] ] }
                },
                "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-instance" ] ]} }]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceSecurityGroup":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, " ingress security group" ] ] },
                "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId" },
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "8080",
                        "ToPort": "8080",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup"}
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceProfile": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "Roles": [ { "Ref": "EC2InstanceRole" } ]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": { "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ] },
                            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [ "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role" ]
            }
        },
        "ElbSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, " ELB ingress security group" ] ] },
                "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId"},
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ],
                "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "-elb-sg" ] ] } } ]
            }
        },
        "ElasticLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "CrossZone": "false",
                "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup" } ],
                "Listeners": [
                    {
                        "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
                        "InstancePort": "8080",
                        "Protocol": "http"
                    }

                ],
                "Instances": [ { "Ref": "EC2Instance"} ],
                "Subnets": [ { "Ref": "SubnetId"} ]
            }
        },
        "EcsCluster": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
        },
        "EcsTaskDefinition": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "Properties": {
                "ContainerDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "jenkins",
                        "Image": "someaccount/jenkins:ecs",
                        "Memory": 995,
                        "PortMappings": [ { "ContainerPort": 8080, "HostPort": 8080 } ],
                        "MountPoints": [
                            {
                                "SourceVolume": "docker",
                                "ContainerPath": "/var/run/docker.sock"
                            },
                            {
                                "SourceVolume": "jenkins_home",
                                "ContainerPath": "/var/jenkins_home"
                            }
                        ]
                    }


                ],
                "Volumes": [
                    {
                        "Name": "jenkins_home",
                        "Host": { "SourcePath": "/ecs/jenkins_home" }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "docker",
                        "Host": { "SourcePath": "/var/run/docker.sock" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "EcsService": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
            "Properties": {
                "Cluster": { "Ref": "EcsCluster" },
                "TaskDefinition": { "Ref": "EcsTaskDefinition" },
                "DesiredCount": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs":{
        "ElbDomainName": {
            "Description": "Public DNS name of Elastic Load Balancer",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ElasticLoadBalancer",
                    "DNSName"
                ]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceDomainName": {
            "Description": "Public DNS name of EC2 instance",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "EC2Instance",
                    "PublicDnsName"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Below are the events of failure:

### [image]

This error occurs after hours.

ECS instance goes active, so AMI image(`ami-05958d7635caa4d04`) looks fine. but there is no task in `Running` or `Stopped` state.

To troubleshoot ECS task, I tried `docker-compose` approach:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
    external: true

services:
  jenkins:
    image: someaccount/jenkins:ecs
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

and  I see that `docker-compose up -d` launches the container in my laptop

---

After ECS instance(`t2.micro`) goes active, I tried manually running new task, I get below error:

[image]

In Cloudformation tempate, `EcsTaskDefinition` has `"Memory": 995`

---

When the computing platform is Linux server(VM), we analyse logs and troubleshoot.

How to troubleshoot this problem? in ECS environment of public cloud

Comment: When the CFN stack is creating the ECS service, could you please open the ECS service in the AWS Management Console and look at the service events? Seeing those here would help to understand what ist going on.

Comment: @MartinLöper Are you asking to followinng these steps? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ecs_cwet.html

Comment: @MartinLöper when CFN stack is creating the ECS service, One thing I observed is, if I manually start my task in existing cluster. It gives `resource:memory` error... Query updated

Comment: @MartinLöper Instead of ECS, now we are using kubenetes, can you please comment on this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64379105/3317808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t2.micro`
instance that you are trying to launch has total memory capacity of 1 GiB.

ECS will try to launch the task into your cluster but it will realize that it cannot meet the requirements because your container instance doesn't have enough available memory (OS processes consume more than 5 MiB of memory) and your task requires `"Memory": 995` which is exactly the issue.

Debugging the container itself will not help in this case as there is nothing wrong with it (probably). It is simply the fact that ECS scheduler is unable to meet the specified requirements to launch the task, therefore it cannot do anything else other than failing and giving a "helpful" message.

There are various things that can cause scheduler to fail to launch a task and it should always give a hint about the problem. In you case, it "clearly" states that you don't have enough memory. Other thing to look for are daemon tasks that can be launched only once per container instance (this accidentally happened to me).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203437/discussion-on-answer-by-matus-dubrava-ecs-service-did-not-stabilize).

Comment: Instead of ECS, now we are using kubenetes, can you please comment on this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64379105/3317808